# Getting PlaylistItems by Page Number in YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

Okay, lets say I have a YouTube playlist with 500 items in them. YouTube's PlaylistItems end-point only allows you to retrieve 50 items at a time:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

After 50 items, it gives you a `nextPageToken` which you can use to specify in your query to get the next page. Doing this, you could iterate through the entire playlist to get all 500 items in 10 queries.

However, what if I only wanted to get the last page? Page 10?

In YouTube's V2 API,  you could have told it to start the index at position 451, and then it would give you the results for 451-500. This doesn't seem to be an option in their V3 API. Now, it seems if I wanted to get just page 10, I would have to iterate through the entire playlist once again, throw out the first 9 pages, and then just take the 10th page.

This seems like a HUGE waste of resources and the cURL operations alone could be a killer.

So is it possible to set the starting index in the V3 API like in the V2 API?

Comment: There's nothing documented right now, although looking at the nextPageToken strings that are returned it appears that they are always the same for the same number of maxResults (that is, is you're always doing maxResults=50, the nextPageToken to get page 2 will be the same regardless of the value of 'q', as will the nextPageToken to get page 3, page 4, etc.) This doesn't seem like something you'd want to rely on in a production app, but it's feasible to figure out what the "page 10, 50 results" token would be ...

Comment: Definitely not something I would want to use.

Answer (score -1):

You can still use a start index but you have to generate the corresponding page token yourself.

As far as you can tell from observation, page tokens are basically a byte sequence encoded in base64, with the first byte always being `8`, and the last two being `16, 0`. We generate tokens somewhat like this (using python 3):

```
i = 451
k = i // 128
i -= 128 * (k - 1)
b = [8, index]
if k > 1 or i > 127: b += [k]
b += [16, 0]
t = base64.b64encode(bytes(f)).decode('utf8').strip('=')
```

The hindmost operation removes the trailing '`=`' characters that are used to fill incomplete blocks in base64. The result ('`CMMDEAA`') is your page token.